# Nested Fieldsets breaks forms inputs within UI Components

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I am building a form within admin of magento 2 using ui components and want to organise the fields within fieldsets like below:

```
<fieldset name="ticket">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ticket</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <field name="ticketingo_tickets_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">ticket</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <fieldset>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Customer Information</label>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        </settings>
        <!--Fields within this nested fieldset no longer function-->
        <field name="customer_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Customer Name</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">ticket</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    ...
</fieldset>
```

However my form breaks as soon as I attempt to add a child fieldset to the main fieldset. Any inputs within the new fieldset values include the new fieldsets in the name and i do not really cant this. I have tried with containers to achieve similar but not much luck and really just want these collapsible fieldsets to work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the dataScope setting node as empty seemed to stop fieldsets from adding additional scopes to names of inputs etc and my form started working fine.

```
<fieldset name="ticket-issue">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Issue Overview</label>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <opened>true</opened>
            <!--Added Below to fieldsets-->
            <dataScope></dataScope>
        </settings>
        ...
```